Tauri - LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '...\Project\src-tauri\target\debug\build\initial-tauri-18f3a34e9ab864b9\out\resource.lib'
This is my first time using Tauri, so, I'm making a ReactJS application using Vite, and I wanted to have Tauri too.
I've installed the prerequisites as the docs suggested:

C++ Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022.
Rust lang.
NodeJS.
Microsoft Edge Web View.

Then I made a Tauri app using NPM, however, everytime I run:
npm run tauri dev

I get the following error:
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
# ...
# Long error message, I've attached the whole message in a screenshot
# ...
= note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\Hashem's\Development\ReactJS\Initial-Tauri\src-tauri\target\debug\build\initial-tauri-18f3a34e9ab864b9\out\resource.lib'

I made a new project just for this problem, and I followed these exact steps:

Created a Tauri application using the command:

npm create tauri-app


Chose TypeScript/JavaScript as the Front-End language.
Chose NPM as my package manager.
Chose ReactJS as my UI template.
Hit the command to install all modules:

npm i

Everything so far has gone great and no problems, and I'm able to run the ReactJS' part normally with no issues using the command:
npm run dev

However, when I run Tauri using the command:
npm run tauri dev

The ReactJS' part still runs, but Tauri's doesn't, and all I get is this following monstrosity of an error:
A screenshot of the error
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
# ...
# Long error message, I've attached the whole message in a screenshot
# ...
= note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'D:\Hashem's\Development\ReactJS\Initial-Tauri\src-tauri\target\debug\build\initial-tauri-18f3a34e9ab864b9\out\resource.lib'

For anyone wanting to check the code of the project, you can find it here:
[https://gitlab.usol.ca/hashem-wannous/initial-tauri/]
I'd like to add: I've never written any code manually, everything I did was running the NPM commands mentioned above, but I thought seeing the configuration might be helpful in some way.

Do you really have a folder named Hashem's with a single quote? And if yes, can you try in a folder using only alphanumeric characters (letters, digits, underscore)?

@Jmb I tried editing the name, it didn't work tho.

@Jmb However, after editing the name, I made a new Tauri project with the said steps, and it worked just fine, whilst the old one didn't.
